# Numpy linear regression with regularization

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm not seeing what is wrong with my code for regularized linear regression. Unregularized I have simply this, which I'm reasonably certain is correct:

```
import numpy as np

def get_model(features, labels):
    return np.linalg.pinv(features).dot(labels)
```

Here's my code for a regularized solution, where I'm not seeing what is wrong with it:

```
def get_model(features, labels, lamb=0.0):
    n_cols = features.shape[1]
    return linalg.inv(features.transpose().dot(features) + lamb * np.identity(n_cols))\
            .dot(features.transpose()).dot(labels)
```

With the default value of 0.0 for lamb, my intention is that it should give the same result as the (correct) unregularized version, but the difference is actually quite large.

Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: I'm starting regularization, and would regularizing a linear regression line produce a curve?

Comment: No. you will still get linear coefficients. Regularization will just change the slope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is:

`features.transpose().dot(features)` may not be invertible. And numpy.linalg.inv works only for full-rank matrix according to the documents. However, a (non-zero) regularization term always makes the equation nonsingular.

By the way, you are right about the implementation. But it is not efficient. An efficient way to solve this equation is the least squares method.

`np.linalg.lstsq(features, labels)` can do the work for `np.linalg.pinv(features).dot(labels)`.

In a general way, you can do this

```
def get_model(A, y, lamb=0):
    n_col = A.shape[1]
    return np.linalg.lstsq(A.T.dot(A) + lamb * np.identity(n_col), A.T.dot(y))
```

Comment: If you use np.linalg.lstsq(), how do you fit in the regularization term `lamb`?

Comment: That works nicely! Thanks. I ended up with `np.linalg.lstsq(...)[0]` because I otherwise get a tuple returned. Also, do you by any chance know why `lstsq()` is more performant?

Comment: lstsq() solves a linear equation. inv() will compute the inversion of a matrix. Solving a linear equation will be faster than computing inversion. Another part of performance gain is from A.T.dot(A) which will be n-by-n matrix assuming A is m-by-n. For most of linear regression problem, m is much larger than n, i.e. number of samples is much larger than number of features. Solving n-by-n linear equation will be faster than solving m-by-n linear equation.

Comment: For Ax=b, least square solves A.T.dot(A).dot(x) = A.T.dot(b). Here you are already solving a least square problem, so you should use `np.linalg.solve` instead of `np.linalg.lstsq`, otherwise you'll experience numerical problems, as I did.

Comment: *Aᵀ·A + λI* is guaranteed to be positive-definite (and therefore invertible) as long as *λ ≠ 0*. In that case you should use `solve` rather than `lstsq` since it's faster and more numerically precise.

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer uses `np.linalg.lstsq`, which uses SVD under the hood (if I remember how LAPACK dgelsd work correctly), I'll show another way of doing regularized regression using SVD:

```py
def lsqL2(A, y, lamb=1e-10):
    U,S,Vt = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    return Vt.T@((U.T@y)*(S/(S**2+lamb)))
```

The comments mention using `np.linalg.solve`, so here is another one that solves the normal equation

```py
def lsqL2b(A, y, lamb=1e-10):
    AtA = A.T@A
    AtA.flat[::AtA.shape[0]+1] += lamb
    return np.linalg.solve(AtA, A.T@y)
```